# How to test that all items of list a are in list b

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of search terms, and a setence.  I need to test that the sentence contains all the search terms:

```
var searchTerms = "fox jumped".Split(' ');
var sentence = "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog".Split(' ');
var test = sentence.Contains(searchTerms);
```

I exptected test to be True -- howerver I get a compile error:
'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains(System.Linq.IQueryable, TSource)' has some invalid arguments

How should I test that sentence contains all the search terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to check whether there are any search terms that don't appear in the sentence:

```
if (!searchTerms.Except(sentence, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase).Any())
```

Comment: Would searchTerms.Any(term => !sentence.Contains(term)) perform faster, or would they both compile to the same IL? (Gotta love IEnumerable)

Comment: @jbehren: That's much slower.  It's ​O(n²), since it needs to loop over the other list every time.

Comment: It seems that .Except follows the same behavior pattern, except that it slims the lists down to distinct values first (which means it's iterating the lists MORE than the .Any method):
http://www.hookedonlinq.com/ExceptOperator.ashx 

Basically, creating the set difference seems like it's going to follow the same path. (I say "seems" because I don't know the inner workings of LINQ)

Comment: @jbehren: Wrong.  `Except` builds a HashSet, and is thus O(n).

Comment: That makes sense then. Thanks for taking the time :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
//test if all of the terms are in the sentence
searchTerms.All(term => sentence.Contains(term));
```